# Examples of exponential time linear space exact algorithms

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

I am looking for examples of NP-complete problem-solving exact algorithms with a linear space complexity and an exponential time complexity. Algorithms which solve the k-SAT problem exactly (such as DPLL and PPSZ) are good examples. Indeed, the space they require is at most linear in the number of variables of the formulas given as input. Are there NP-complete problems for which there are (well-studied and non-trivial) exponential time & linear space algorithms?

Comment: I don't know if this counts as well-studied, hence why this is a comment, but most of the NPC problems I can think of can be solved by considering either all subsets or all permutations of the input set (depending on the problem). Both can be done with linear space.

Comment: Do you mean algorithms that take exponential time, or problems that require exponential time?   It is easy to write down an example of an algorithm that uses exponential time even though it might not be optimal.  What prevents you from doing that?    A question asking for many examples might be too broad/open-ended to be a good fit here.